# How can i access and change a value in an object with an array of keys

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
const object = {
    key1: 'example_key1',
    key2: {
        key3: 'example_key2'
    }
}

const string = 'key1'
const array = ['key2', 'key3']

object[string] = 'foo' // Work
object[array] = 'bar' // Dont work
```

How can I access and change the object with the array of keys?

I have tried `loadash.get` but it can only get values not change them.

Comment: What do you expect `object[array]` to return?

Comment: Object[index] is what you need, so if you give object[array[0]] would work. But If you want all values you need to be initialied to bar then it's separate story

Comment: Will the array always be of a length of 2 or it may be longer ?

Comment: Yes, the array could change. And be longer or shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like the following:

```
function set(obj, path, value) {
  var schema = obj
  var len = path.length
  for(var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    var elem = path[i]
    if (!schema[elem] ) schema[elem] = {}
    schema = schema[elem]
  }

  schema[path[len-1]] = value
}
```

And then you could use it in the following way:

```
set(object, array, 'someText')
```

With a function like the above `set` you can update an object passing an array of nested keys and the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```js
const object = {
    key1: 'example_key1',
    key2: {
        key3: 'example_key2'
    }
}

const string = 'key1'
const array = ['key2', 'key3']

console.log(object[array[0]][array[1]])
```

**EDIT**

First solution is static. Below solution is more dynamic:

```js
const object = {
    key1: 'example_key1',
    key2: {
        key3: 'example_key2'
    }
}

const object2 = {
    key1: 'example_key1',
    key2: {
        key3: {
           key4: "example_key3"
        }
    }
}


const string = 'key1'
const array = ['key2', 'key3']

let nestedObj = undefined;
array.forEach(val => {
   if (nestedObj) nestedObj = nestedObj[val];
   else nestedObj = object[val];
})
console.log(nestedObj)

const array2 = ['key2', 'key3', 'key4']

let nestedObj2 = undefined;
array2.forEach(val => {
   if (nestedObj2) nestedObj2 = nestedObj2[val];
   else nestedObj2 = object2[val];
})
console.log(nestedObj2)
```

Comment: what is that you are doing here?

Comment: This works, but if I change the array, I need to manually add `array[2]`.

Comment: @PowerKuu I added a dynamic solution to my answer =)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function and and check if the key from the object exist in the array, if so then change the key value in the object

```js
const object = {
  key1: 'example_key1',
  key2: {
    key3: 'example_key2'
  },
  key3: 'someVal'
}

const array = ['key2', 'key3']

function doRecursion(obj) {
  for (let keys in obj) {
    if (array.includes(keys)) {
      console.log(typeof obj[keys])
      if (typeof obj[keys] === 'object') {
        doRecursion(obj[keys])
      } else {
        obj[keys] = 'bar';
      }
    } else {
      console.log(keys)
    }

  }
  return obj
};

console.log(doRecursion(object));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here recurtion will make things easier

```js
function get(obj, keys) {
  if(typeof keys === 'string') {
    return obj[keys];
  }
  const key = keys.shift();
  return keys.length ? get(obj[key], keys) : obj[key];
}

const object1 = {
    key1: 'example_key1',
    key2: {
        key3: 'example_key2'
    }
}

const object2 = {
    key1: 'example_key1',
    key2: {
        key3: {
           key4: "example_key3"
        }
    }
}

const string = 'key1'
const array1 = ['key2', 'key3'];
const array2 = ['key2', 'key3', 'key4'];

console.log(get(object1, string));
console.log(get(object1, array1));
console.log(get(object2, array2));
```